# Quarter Equivalent for MySQL Data Summation

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by

I am using the following mySQL query for summing up "volume" column for each month

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m-%Y") AS Month, 
       SUM(vol) 
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m-%Y") 
order by Month
```

It produces the right output as expected on monthly basis:

[image]

(Above is image capture from excel)

Now, I want to change it to quarterly (i.e. 3-monthly) summation, or six-monthly summation.

What changes are needed to the above query? 
I am unable to find any equivalent of `%m` for quarter or for six-month, hence the question.

Comment: Quarterly or six monthly - based on what, current calendar year, current tax year, going back forever, over the last year from this month end..?

Comment: @P.Salmon - quarterly/6-monthly - based on standard months. That is - ending March, June, Sep and Dec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this per quarter, you can do:

```
select year(date) yr, quarter(date) qr, sum(vol) sum_vol
from tbl
group by yr, qr
order by yr, qr
```

Or if you want to concatenate the year and quarter in a single column:

```
select concat(year(date), '-Q', quarter(date)) yr_qr, sum(vol) sum_vol
from tbl
group by yr_qr
order by yr_qr
```

To split by semester, you need a little more work:

```
select 
    concat(year(date), '-S', case when month(date) between 1 and 6 then 1 else 2 end) yr_sr, 
    sum(vol) 
from tbl
group by yr_sr
order by yr_sr
```